# Fetch is not workin, Next js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I have an issue with Next.js. The problem is that when trying to make a fetch to an API request, I encounter this:
[consola](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt2tF.png)
and I'm not sure why. I've already deleted the database of my API, so it shouldn't be showing me that.
When trying to access the same route with Postman, it perfectly reflects the data.
this is my code:

```
async function loadImg(){
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/getImages")
  const data = await res.json()
  return data
}


export default async function ImgPage() {
  const imgs = await loadImg()
  console.log(imgs)

  return (
    <div>
      {imgs.map((img)=>(
        <div key={img._id}>

          <h3>{img.date}</h3>
          <img src={"http://localhost:4000/files/"+img.filename} alt={img.originalname}></img>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

What I hope for is that it reflects my API data. Do you know if Next.js has some sort of internal memory or something that could be showing me that?,I created the API myself, my backend (api) is at localhost://4000/api/getImages and my app is at localhost://3000/images.

Comment: unless new versions of react allow this - you can't make your react component async. You need to use `useEffect` to load the images. then store them in state to access them in the component. the component will re-render when the images are fetched and state is updated. Also, try wrapping your fetch request in a try/catch. see if you're getting an error or something

Comment: Please use `axios` module instead of `fetch` method. In before, I met same issue, atm, I solved this problem using `axios`.

Comment: @DevConductor fetch is fine, why add another dependency? This isn't a solution to the problem anyhow.

Comment: @DevConductor - There's no reason to skip using `fetch()` here.  That's just a recommendation without a reason.  If you specifically need some feature that `axios()` provides that `fetch()` doesn't, then OK, but not for this specific case.

Comment: By default NextJS put data in cache when using fetch. You can check here : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#opting-out-of-data-caching how to disable the cache

Comment: Yes, it was the cache the problem, I already fixed it, thank you @OneQ

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have change this part of the code, fetch('localhost:4000/api/getImages',**{cache:"no-store"})**, on line two. It seems that if you use a fetch, it gets stored in the cache, and how did this affect me? For some reason, it was fetching cached data, and that's why it wasn't making the request to my API. As a result, it wasn't reflecting the data I was fetching from my API. You can read more about this here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#opting-out-of-data-caching

```js
async function loadImg(){
  const imgGet= await fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/getImages',{cache:"no-store"})
  const imgs= await imgGet.json()
  return imgs

}


export default async function ImgPage() {
   const imgs = await loadImg()

  
   return (
    <div>
      {imgs.map((img)=>(
        <div key={img._id}>

          <h3>{img.date}</h3>
          <img src={"http://localhost:4000/files/"+img.filename} alt={img.originalname}></img>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: What did you change, other than some variable names?  Please add to your answer a description of what you changed and why that solved your problem.

Comment: Change this part of the code, fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/getImages',{cache:"no-store"}), on line two. It seems that if you use a fetch, it gets stored in the cache, and how did this affect me? For some reason, it was fetching cached data, and that's why it wasn't making the request to my API. As a result, it wasn't reflecting the data I was fetching from my API. You can read more about this here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#opting-out-of-data-caching

Comment: Then, please EDIT your answer to explain what you changed and why - to make it a good and most useful answer.  Answers should not be a puzzle for people to try to figure out.  It should be simple and quick to read what the problem was.  You can use the "edit" link below the answer to fix it.

Comment: FYI, you can also control caching from your server too if you never want these images cached.  Usually images are not dynamic and caching is efficient.